# The meaning of **/* in the Ant script

Tags: java, ant

In the following Ant script, what is the meaning of `**/*`?

```
<fileset dir="${server.src}" casesensitive="yes">
<include name="**/*.java"/>    
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`**` means any level of subdirectory

i.e. match `a/x.java`, `a/b/y.java`, `a/b/c/z.java`, etc.